# How to write Spark Optimization to recalculate DataFrame when array column contains more values than a threshold?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

- Spark 2.1.0 with Scala 2.10.6

I've been looking for tutorials and help regarding extending Spark Catalyst optimization using custom rules. All the examples I have found are quite basic and usually use the Multiplication with a 1 as an example to show a logical rule. 
I wanted to ask is it possible to write a custom rule for the following case.

I have a dataframe with an array in a column (column _2). The array contains N values for each row. I need to recalculate this dataframe with a new value M such that the array would now contain M values. Now the optimization I want to apply is that if N>M, the strategy should just return the dataframe with the top M values instead of recalculating the entire dataframe. Otherwise call the function to calculate the dataframe. So basically

```
Rule (distance:Dataframe, M:int){
    distance.registerTempTable("tab1")
    val N=sqlContext.sql("select size(_2) from tab1")
    if(N>M){
        // Query to select only top M values from column _2 to create distanceNew
        return distanceNew
    }else{
        //call function to calculate distance from scratch (A time consuming process)
        return getNNeighbors(distance,M)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to write such a custom Rule in Spark Catalyst, if so can I get some guidance on how to do it? Or is there any other way to define custom run time optimization rules based on pattern matching on Spark SQL that I can use.

I already have written a function that does this, but my aim is to write it in some optimization pattern matching API as a prove of concept that generic rules can be written to optimize algorithms.

Comment: This looks very close to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720852/spark-optimization-rules-for-functions (except that one is abstracted to the point it's not clear what you want). Which is the one you most need an answer to?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I wrote this question, And doing more research on Catalyst i concluded this cant really be done in catalyst. So I made a more general question, The end objective of both is the same I want to write an optimization rule that will let me return a subset of the existing dataframe (or RDD, i have both implementations) if the newer calculations are subset of the existing one. If it can be achieved with Catalyst, than thats great, if not, is there any other way of declaring optimization rules in spark i can use. Sorry for redundantly asking the question separately

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul My research has shown that Catalyst is the only API spark provides for writing optimization rules and strategies, and there is no other API available which can be used to write more generic rules that could apply to function calls. Or did i miss something in my research

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correct, you want to recreate the `array` in your `dataframe` if the condition matches. right? If that is the case then you don't need to recreate `dataframe`, just use `udf` funtion
following is not the complete solution but should be helpful 

define the `udf` funtion , assuming that the `array` is of `double` values

```
def testUdf = udf((value: Array[Double], M : Int) => {
    val N = value.size
    if(N > M) //return the new array
    else //return the array you need
  })
```

and call it with the following

```
dataframe.withColumn("column 2 name", testUdf(dataframe("column 2 name")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think your case has anything to do with Spark SQL's Optimizer Rules (or batches thereof) as an optimization rule would have to work with the content of the (business) data not the structure of the query or the dataset. It would not be a optimization rule but a Dataset transformation.

I don't think it merits a new optimization rule.

With that said, why don't you do the following:

```
// check the length of the array column
val theArrayColumn = ...
val size = distance.select(size(theArrayColumn) as "size").orderBy("size").as[Int].head
val inputDF = if (size > M) {
  recalculateDistance()
} else {
  // we're fine
  distance
}
getNNeighbors(inputDF)
```

If you describe `getNNeighbors` with more detail, that could get even simpler.

`size` is a function in [functions object](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$).